# AFNetworking downloadTaskWithRequest:progress:destination:completionHandler: not writing file to the path

Tags: ios, ios8, afnetworking-2

I am trying to download a file using AFNetworking (2.5.4). The download completes, the completion handler is called, with error set to nil, everything seeming fine, but the destination file does not exist:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
NSString *fullPath = [valid path from my apps local manager]
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:req progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
    return [NSURL URLWithString:fullPath];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Saved file to %@.", filePath);
    *** [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath.absoluteString] returns NO here ***
}];
[cell.progressView setProgressWithDownloadProgressOfTask:downloadTask animated:YES];
[downloadTask resume];
```

The file path is a regular path that my app has write access to:

`/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/APP-GUID-REDACTED/Documents/FILE-NAME-REDACTED.docx`

I was using a different method before AFNetworking, and it could write to the exact same path just fine. HTTP response headers show everything perfectly (status 200, correct content length etc.) and if I curl the download URL it downloads the file with no issues. There's no problem with the file.

Why is my destination file not written in completion handler despite no errors?

**UPDATE:** I've also tried `AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];` but it changes nothing. I've also tried creating an `NSProgress` pointer and sending that for the `progress` argument, but no avail.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use **[NSURL fileURLWithPath:]** (not URLWithString).

```
return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fullPath];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is **wrong file path or invalid file path**. I had same problem here.

Create path like given below :

```
NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
NSURL *filePathURL = [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"your file name here",i]];
```

Now use above path :

```
NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:req progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
    return filePathURL;
}
```

Comment: Copy-pasted, nothing changed. Your code produces the exact same path as mine, and it's again nil.